# Автоматизация клика

Tags: автоматизация

У меня есть 1100 страниц, на каждой их этих страниц есть фотография, у каждой страницы схожие сслыки, меняется только число, к примеру: 
https://xxxx-xxxx.ru/xxxx/xxxx/1_item.png 
https://xxxx-xxxx.ru/xxxx/xxxx/2_item.png 
и т.д
Если ли программа\сайт что бы автоматически скачать эти изображения с каждой страницы, wget не работает, я пробовал, только если в ручную заходить и скачивать, а это очень долго.

Comment: Вам должен подойти Free Download Manager. [Скачать можно тут](https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/). Указывайте путь к папке в котором лежат картинки и выбираете нужные или скачиваете папку полностью Удачи.

Answer (score 0):

Так, мысли вслух. На этих же страницах есть кнопка сохранить. Тогда до этой кнопки можно добраться с клавы кнопкой Tab, а это уже ближе к .js. Вот эмитация нажатия клавиш:

```js
//https://subscribe.ru/archive/comp.soft.win.faqmsdos/200902/16044800.html
WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

theCalculator = WshShell.Exec("calc");           // Запустим калькулятор
WScript.Sleep(3000);                             // Ждем 3 секунды
WshShell.AppActivate(theCalculator.ProcessID);   // Активируем окно запущенного приложения
// WshShell.SendKeys("1{+}2~")                   // Пошлём 1 + 2 Enter

WshShell.SendKeys("1")                          // Пошлём 1 
WScript.Sleep(3000);                            // Ждем 3 секунды

WshShell.SendKeys("{+}")                        // Пошлём +
WScript.Sleep(3000);                            // Ждем 3 секунды

WshShell.SendKeys("2")                         // Пошлём 2 
WScript.Sleep(3000);                                 // Ждем 3 секунды

WshShell.SendKeys("~")                          // Пошлём Enter
```

Вот .js для открытия (возможно, нескольких) URL:

```js
var navOpenInNewWindow = 0x1;
var navOpenInNewTab = 0x800;
var navOpenInBackgroundTab = 0x1000;

var intLoop = 0;
var intArrUBound = 0;
var navFlags = navOpenInBackgroundTab;
var arrstrUrl = new Array(3);
var objIE;

    intArrUBound = arrstrUrl.length;


    arrstrUrl[0] = "http://bing.com/";
    arrstrUrl[1] = "http://google.com/";
    arrstrUrl[2] = "http://msn.com/";
    arrstrUrl[3] = "http://yahoo.com/";

    objIE = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
    objIE.Navigate2(arrstrUrl[0]);

    for (intLoop=1;intLoop<=intArrUBound;intLoop++) {

        objIE.Navigate2(arrstrUrl[intLoop], navFlags);

    }

    objIE.Visible = true;
    objIE = null;

//Как открыть ie с помощью .js файла?
```

Можно попробовать это все соединить, а для запуска этого файла .js написать .bat c

```
for /I
```

параметр-то числовой.